# Помогите сохранить запись в XML при помощи fwrite

Tags: php, xml

Здрасте! Есть вот такое дело:

```
$file_name = 'export.xml'; // название файла
$file = fopen($file_name,"w"); // открываем файл для записи, если его нет, то создаем его
fwrite($file,trim($peremen) ); // записываем в файл строки
fclose($file); // закрываем файл
```

Он создает ТХТ, а мне нужно что бы записывал в XML в windows-1251

Answer (score 0):

Вставил ваш код. Всё работает так, как вам нужно! Ошибки нет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Изменение кодировки делается так

```
fwrite($file,iconv('UTF-8','WINDOWS-1251','$peremen') ); // записываем в файл строки
```

Comment: Я раньше так пробовал, она записывает сразу в двух кодировках поочереди. Вверху 1251, в низу ютф-8  , а на xml файл всё ругается говорит что это тхт

Comment: Я все у себя проверил. В том числе изменения кодировок. Всё прекрасно работает. Извините, не могу предположить, где у вас ошибка.

Comment: Вы пробовали куда то этот XML скормить?  Хотя бы сайтмап из него сделать и в гугл залить, он скажет что неправильный формат...  Вот это и тревожит :(

Comment: Создал сайтмап с кириллицей.  Запустил. Файл создался. Залил на гугл диск. Открыл в HML Editey, да и просто, через пред. просмотр. Всё отображается. Ошибок нет. Может, вас не правильно понял?

Comment: я имел ввиду не хранилице дисковое, а скормить в кабинете вебмастера (к примеру)  У меня ругается и гугл и яндекс и все торговые площадки на файл который создает этот код, пишет что неправильный формат - не XML это